# how to measure how many steps will a script take to execute to produce a solution

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, pipe, performance-testing

So there are ways to observe how much time it takes for a script or a program to generate a solution.
but is there a way to determine how many exact number of steps it took to produce the solution?

one possible way to solve which I could think of was to add additional logic inside the script/program to make it return how many steps it took(basically putting a counter inside all the for loops and recursion calls).

but is there a way to do this from an external script?

also, how do these competitive programming platforms like HackerEarth measure the code's speed?
do they just run the program multiple times against the test cases, calculate the time it took and average it?
or do they have a mechanism to see the exact number of steps that the program took to execute and produce a solution

Comment: They just run it the one time on a virtual machine, using the start and end times to get a duration. Keep in mind that running code costs money so running multiple times isn't likely to happen when getting a precise average time isn't really necessary.

Comment: How do you define "steps" here? Instructions? Function calls? Does it include child functions, and how deep do you want to count? 
If you are talking about how much CPU time a thread uses, in C, you can use clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, *tm) (or use CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID if you want to cound the process CPU time) to get the thread CPU time at the beginning of your code block, and get it again after your code block and get the differences. 
If you are talking about duration the program run, you can follow @Ouroborus's suggestion. 
If you want to know what cost high, man perf.

Comment: @Ouroborus but isn't that a bit inaccurate, say there were other processes running on the virtual machine and our program lagged a bit. Wouldn't it just declare it as wrong submission even though our code took a valid number of steps

Comment: @kevingodfrey There's only the one process (aside from standard OS-related stuff) running on each VM. They're each spun up specifically to handle one request and the cores/memory they use aren't shared. A time estimate is all they really need and, if it's off by a few milliseconds, it doesn't matter. I'm not sure what you mean about "steps". There's no useful way to use a count of discrete operations as a metric.